Local chart of log schemes
In the 1st paragraph of page 3 of This paper it says:

Any fine saturated log scheme $X$ which is smooth
over $\mathbb C$ (in the sense of Grothendieck’s general notion of smoothness) is etale locally isomorphic to a log scheme $\mathbb C[P]/I$, where P is a finitely generated, integral, and saturated monoid, and $I$ is an ideal generated by an ideal of $P$.

It comes very weird to me, for example if $X=Spec \mathbb C[x,y]$ with log structure $\mathbb N$ given by mapping $n$ to $x^n$ (so it's the log structure induced by the divisor $V(x)$), how to identify $X$ with such a quotient?

The quote is not exact – Ogus writes about "idealized smooth" log schemes. Please include the exact quote to avoid confusion.
In general, a smooth log scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ (with trivial log structure) is etale locally of the form ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb{C}[P])$ for an fs monoid $P$. In particular, there is no ideal $I$ in the picture.
Ogus develops the more general theory of "idealized log schemes" and of idealized smoothness. Without getting into the details here, an idealized smooth log scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ is one locally of the form ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb{C}[P]/I)$ for an fs monoid $P$ and an ideal $I$ generated by an ideal of $P$. These are not smooth as log schemes over $\mathbb{C}$ (in "Grothendieck's sense" or otherwise). Ogus equips them with the extra structure of a "sheaf of ideals" in $\mathcal{M}_X$, making them objects in the category of "idealized log schemes". In this richer category they are indeed "smooth", as he writes. However, it seems that in practice it is often fine to forget the extra structure.
What is this for? If $X$ is a smooth log scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ and $Z\subseteq X$ is a locally closed subscheme cut out by an ideal in the log structure (for example, a log stratum, or a closure of a stratum), then while not smooth, $Z$ is idealized smooth. Moreover, the restriction map on log differentials
$$ \Omega^1_X |_Z \to \Omega^1_Z $$
is an isomorphism! So not only is $\Omega^1_Z$ locally free (even though $Z$ is not smooth) – it looks as if the inclusion map $Z\to X$ was etale in some sense. These facts and the idea of working with idealized smooth log schemes from the outset allow us to prove facts about smooth log schemes (no ideal) by induction on the log stratification.
(Another natural situation when you would want to consider idealized smooth log schemes which are not smooth is the special fibre of a semistable reduction over $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$: it is log smooth over the log point ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{C})$, but it is also idealized smooth over $\mathbb{C}$ with no log structure.)
To address your example, here $X$ is smooth, and in the neighborhood of $0$ given by $\{y\neq - 1\}$ has a chart by the monoid $P = \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}$ given by $$ (1, 0) \mapsto x, \qquad (0, 1)\mapsto 1 + y; $$
the ideal $I$ is the zero ideal. To cover the entire $X$ you need another chart on the open subset $\{y\neq 0\}$ given by $(1,0)\mapsto x$ and $(0,1)\mapsto y$.
